# JQuery dropdown select onchange nearby class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a partial view that gets called to add a new row everytime a button is clicked on. The end result looks like this:

[image]

Important thing to note is that Document Categories makes an ajax call and populates Document Fields

What I have done so far is change Document Categories to a class and currently only the FIRST Document Categories works and it somehow changes all the Document Fields instead of the one next to itself.

How do I make sure a class can only change the class next to itself?

JQuery for Document Categories that makes an ajax request and updates Document Fields

```
function refreshDropdown(Input) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetFields", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(Input),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                $(".Fields").empty();
                $(".Fields").append("<option value>Select Field</option>");
                $.each(result.fields, function (key, value) {
                    $(".Fields").append("<option value="+value.Id+">"+value.Name+"</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}

$("#datatable-search-input-container").on("change", ".Categories", function (e) {
    console.log("changed");
    selected = $(".Categories").find(":selected").val();
    var form_data = selected;
    refreshDropdown(form_data);
    return false;
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label>Document Categories</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, (SelectList)Model.Categories, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control Categories" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label>Document Fields</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldId, (SelectList)Model.DocumentFields, "Select Field", new { @class = "form-control Fields" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 search-spacing">
        <label for="Data">Data</label>
        <input type="text" id="Data" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
selected = $(".Categories").find(":selected").val();
```

change for

```
selected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
```

when the function use `.Class` you can use `$(this)` to get the current object of the action.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I do that it works for all Document Categories but one onchange will change all the Document Fields

Comment: did you replace this $("#datatable-search-input-container").on("change", ".Categories" to this $(".Categories").on("change" i forget to put

Comment: When I do that DocumentCategories stops working again